# How to set UITableView section to stay fixed?

Tags: ios, checkbox, swift3, uitableviewsectionheader

I need to make something that is shown in the picture below. I thought that I should use table view section but there are two problems here:

1. the table view will scroll but I want It to be fix!
2. I want to use checkmark box just like the picture

[image: The example]

Comment: Drag a UIView onto the UITableView in storyboard as HeaderView, it won't scroll and will be fixed there.

Comment: go with `tableview` set scrolling disabled, use custom `UITableViewCell` class to add checkmark

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the SECTION to be fixed but allowing the table view to have scroll, all you have to do is in the interface builder, set the table view style as **grouped**

[image]

Comment: No I want to disable scroll in table view and just like a picture that you can see in the top of this post